# String of number to date in python

Tags: python, date

I have a string of digits:

```
test = '07052019'
```

I need to convert this string into date

```
07/05/2019
```

How do I do this in Python?

Comment: Tried anything yourself? There are dozens of tutorials out there.

Comment: Try doing it by yourself, maybe [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) can help you a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt

def try_parse(data_string: str, format_str: str):
try:
    _d = dt.datetime.strptime(data_string, format_str)
    return _d
except:
    return None
```

For example, in your case:

```
try_parse(test, "%d%m%Y")
print(try_parse('07052019', "%d%m%Y").strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```